# New flutter project Android studio Arctic fox

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter development.
My questions are:

when creating a new flutter project,
what is the android language to choose? java or kotlin.
what IOS language i should select? swift or objective C

[new flutter project Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPS0u.png)

Comment: Good question. If you don't know already, it doesn't matter too much. Go with the defaults. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you (and i always choose this myself) to go for Kotlin and Swift and as they are the newest native langages for Android and IOS respectively.

However it might depend on your app requirements and if you plan for instance to write native code along with dart code.

If so, you will write in the langage (ie. Kotlin or Java and Swift or Objective-C) that you have selected at this moment.

Comment: thanks bro, really helped

Answer (score 1):

The 'old' Android language is Java.
The 'old' iOS language is Objective C.

You should pick Kotlin and Swift, you'll find much more resources on internet to help you with those languages.

Don't worry too much about this choice, nothing will stop you to re-create your Android and iOS project with another language later if needed !
You can even mix Java and Kotlin on Android

Comment: thanks for your great support